# Best way to store CMU Sphinx text output

Tags: java, php, voice-recognition, cmusphinx, jsapi

I am currently building a recognition program with cmu sphinx. I would like to take the speech query that is converted to text by sphinx and store it as a data file (I was thinking either .txt file or .php [due to webserver using .php]).  after the file is stored on the server, I already have the server taking the file, and giving me back the results I asked for (works perfectly).   Just wanted some food for thought on how someone else would go about storing the text generated by sphinx, and what would be the most efficient file type (like I said I think .php would be the best filetype due to webserver, but if someone else has an opinion feel free to share). when the data is received (.xml format) I will have a synthesizer output the data from the webserver.  I want the webserver to store past queries, and create a small offline server database.  I also want the webserver to have multiple users queries stored.

thank you for your time.  Look forward to any answers, or any food for thought.  Cheers!

Comment: There are many ways to store text into a file, most of them are straightforward. Would you mind to elaborate what your issue is exactly?